# how to order by nested list column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

the table is created

```
 CREATE TABLE "Tasks"(
    code VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL
);
```

query

```
select "code" from "Tasks" order by "code" asc
```

result:

[image]

how to make it so:

[image]

There are options on how to do this so that the code field is sorted as needed

**how to sort the list as needed?**

Comment: CREATE TABLE "Tasks"(
    code VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL
);

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbiNd.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBa7X.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is about semantic versioning, then you need to convert the dotted parts into numbers.  You can do that by splitting the string on `.` and then casting the resulting array to `int[]`:

```
# with tasks (code) as (
  values ('0.1'), ('0.1.1'), ('0.1.10'), ('0.1.11'), ('0.1.2'), 
         ('0.1.3'), ('0.2.1'), ('1.1'), ('1.1.1'), ('1.1.10'), ('1.1.2')
)
select * 
  from tasks
 order by string_to_array(code, '.')::int[];

┌────────┐
│  code  │
├────────┤
│ 0.1    │
│ 0.1.1  │
│ 0.1.2  │
│ 0.1.3  │
│ 0.1.10 │
│ 0.1.11 │
│ 0.2.1  │
│ 1.1    │
│ 1.1.1  │
│ 1.1.2  │
│ 1.1.10 │
└────────┘
(11 rows)
```